# Control 'txtUserName' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, visual-studio-2010

I have this error - Control 'txtUserName' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server. I am unable to get rid of it, my text box is placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

The page which I am getting this on is my 'reset password' page I want the users to be able to enter their username and once they press the reset password button it takes them to a page which allows them to change their password.

Here is the code that I am currently working with.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <div style="font-family:Arial">
    <table style="border: 1px solid black; width:300px">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <b>Reset my password</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                User Name
            </td>    
            <td>
                <form action="ChangePassword.aspx" method="get"> 
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" Width="150px" runat="server" 
                ontextchanged="txtUserName_TextChanged">
                </asp:TextBox>

                </form>
            </td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>    
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnResetPassword" runat="server" 
                Width="150px" Text="Reset Password" onclick="btnResetPassword_Click" />
            </td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>    
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says, you need to add a `runat="server"` in the `form` tag. This is just something ASP.NET demands to work.

The way ASP.NET handles events and postbacks forces this requirement. It tries to keep the page's state inside the actual page (called the 'view state'), and on form submission it sends it back. This was invented to make the stateless web stateful.

Just put in the `runat="server"` inside the `form` tag and you will be set.

```
<form runat="server" action="ChangePassword.aspx" method="get">
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried that, this is what my form looks like right now 

<form id="Form1" runat="server" action="ChangePassword.aspx" method="get"> 
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" Width="150px" runat="server" 
                ontextchanged="txtUserName_TextChanged">
                </asp:TextBox>

however I still get the same error

Comment: All ASP.NET elements should be inside a form. You can only have one per page too. Try to widen the `form`s covering area by putting it around your entire page.

Comment: @PatrickHofman "one per page" is not correct. You can have multiple forms on a page as long as they aren't nested, and even multiple forms with `runat="server"` on it so long as only one is `visible` at any given time.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev you might be right. Maybe something from ASP.NET v1?

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes its old... not sure why anyone would want to mess with multiple `runat="server"` forms but it's in some old documentation.

Comment: @KaranRamchandani: Need more help? If not, please accept the answer you liked best, and also review your previous questions.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help with my previous question, I am getting this error message - Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

I am using a Windows 2008 server, and I have tried adding a machine key to the web config file however that didn't fix the problem

Comment: @KaranRamchandani: Can you post that in a new question and put in the necessary code to reproduce?

Comment: Hi Patrick, I was unable to post a new question, as I am restricted to ask a question once every 90 mins which is why I added a comment.

Comment: @KaranRamchandani: It is very hard to reproduce the issue from just one comment. We need definitely more to work this out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28946059/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-ensure-that-machinekey-configuration-speci - here is the link for the new quesiton

Answer (score 0):

Add < form> tag like this...,
it will work..

[image]